# Why are there only $n-1$ principal components for $n$ data if the number of dimensions is $\ge n$?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, eigenvalues

In PCA, when the number of dimensions $d$ is greater than (or even equal to) the number of samples $N$, why is it that you will have at most $N-1$ non-zero eigenvectors? In other words, the rank of the covariance matrix amongst the $d\ge N$ dimensions is $N-1$.

**Example:** Your samples are vectorized images, which are of dimension $d = 640\times480 = 307\,200$, but you only have $N=10$ images.

Comment: Imagine $N=2$ points in 2D or in 3D. What is the dimensionality of the manifold that these points are occupying? The answer is $N-1=1$: two points always lie on a line (and a line is 1-dimensional). The exact dimensionality of the space does not matter (as long as it is larger than $N$), your points only occupy 1-dimensional subspace. So the variance is only "spread" in this subspace, i.e. along 1 dimension. This remains true for any $N$.

Comment: I'd add just an additional precision to @amoeba's comment. Origin point also matters. So, if you have N=2 + origin, the number of dimensions is at utmost 2 (not 1). However, in PCA we usually center the data, which means that we put the origin _inside_ the space of the data cloud - then one dimension gets consumed and the answer will be "N-1", as shown by amoeba.

Comment: This is what confuses me. It's not the centering per se that destroys the dimension, right? If you have exactly N samples and N dimensions, then even after centering you still have N eigenvectors..?

Comment: Why? It is centering that destroys one dimension. Centering (by arithmetic mean) "moves" the origin from "outside" into the space "spanned" by the the data. With the example of N=2. 2 points + some origin generally span a plane. When you center this data, you put the origin on a straight line halfway between the 2 points. So, the data now span only the line.

Comment: Euclid already knew this 2300 years ago: two points determine a line, three points determine a plane.  Generalizing, $N$ points determine an $N-1$ dimensional *Euclidean space*.

Answer (score 33):

Consider what PCA does.  Put simply, PCA (as most typically run) creates a new coordinate system by:

1. shifting the origin to the centroid of your data,
2. squeezes and/or stretches the axes to make them equal in length, and
3. rotates your axes into a new orientation.

(For more details, see this excellent CV thread: [Making sense of principal component analysis, eigenvectors & eigenvalues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691/).)  However, it doesn't just rotate your axes any old way.  Your new $X_1$ (the first principal component) is oriented in your data's direction of maximal variation.  The second principal component is oriented in the direction of the next greatest amount of variation *that is orthogonal to the first principal component*.  The remaining principal components are formed likewise.

With this in mind, let's examine [@amoeba's example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123318/why-are-there-only-n-1-principal-axes-for-n-data-points-if-the-number-of-dim/123349#comment235087_123318).  Here is a data matrix with two points in a three dimensional space:
$$
X = \bigg[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &1 &1  \\
2 &2 &2
\end{array}
\bigg]
$$
Let's view these points in a (pseudo) three dimensional scatterplot:

[image]

So let's follow the steps listed above.  (1) The origin of the new coordinate system will be located at $(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)$.  (2) The axes are already equal.  (3) The first principal component will go diagonally from $(0,0,0)$ to $(3,3,3)$, which is the direction of greatest variation for these data.  Now, the second principal component must be orthogonal to the first, and should go in the direction of the greatest *remaining* variation.  But what direction is that?  Is it from $(0,0,3)$ to $(3,3,0)$, or from $(0,3,0)$ to $(3,0,3)$, or something else?  *There is no remaining variation, so there cannot be any more principal components*.

With $N=2$ data, we can fit (at most) $N-1 = 1$ principal components.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say we have a matrix $X=[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]$ , where each $x_i$ is an obervation (sample) from $d$ dimension space, so $X$ is a $d$ by $n$ matrix, and $d > n$.

**If we first centered the dataset** ,  we have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$, which means: $x_1=-\sum\limits_{i=2}^n x_i$, so the column rank of $X \leq n-1$ , then $rank(X)\leq n-1$.

We know that $rank(XX^T)=rank(X)\leq n-1$ , so $XX^T$ has at most $n-1$ non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: You could elaborate further that $\le n-1$ non-zero eigenvalues corresponds to $\le n-1$ eigenvectors which in turn corresponds to $\le n-1$ principal components

Comment: Add on: for a matrix $M$ of size $m\times m$ , if its rank $r \le m$, meaning the null space ($Mx=0$) has $m-r$ sized orthogonal basis, which means $M$ has $m-r$ zero eigenvalues. So it has $r$ non-zero eigenvalues.