# Maximum number of principal components in PCA. Is sklearn wrong?

Tags: pca, python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction, eigenvalues

Recently I've been interested in applying PCA to a dataset I have and I wanted to develop a deep understanding of what I would actually be doing when I implement it.

Today I encountered two confronting answers to the question of **what is the maximum number of principal components**. The two answers are these ones:

- `maxn_pc = min(n_samples, n_features)`. Supported by [sklearn's documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA)
- Or this formula. Supported by [this flawlessly looking argument](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123318/why-are-there-only-n-1-principal-components-for-n-data-if-the-number-of-dime?newreg=b8f97b279c594f52b2edb58d68ef542b).

  ```
  if n_samples <= n_features:
      maxn_pc = n_samples - 1
  else:
      maxn_pc = n_features
  ```

Do any of you know what is the meaning of that extra component that sklearn's PCA is offering?

Comment: If the number of samples $n$ is less than or equal to the number of features, the $n$-th PC will be constant zero (eigenvalue = 0). This is what `sklearn` will presumably return. The number of non-trivial PCs is $n-1$ as per the linked answer.

Comment: Are you doing PCA with or without centering?

Comment: @whuber I don't think `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` can do PCA without centering. I don't see such an option [in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA).

Comment: @amoeba Completely on point! I just checked what is the n-th principal component of my data and it is always 0! Problem solved :)

Comment: @whuber I'm currently NOT centering the data, but your comment led me to do some research and I'm definitely going to repeat the analysis but this time centering the data. Reasons can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-beneficial-to-center-and-normalize-the-data-before-running-Principal-Component-Analysis-on-it) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22329/how-does-centering-the-data-get-rid-of-the-intercept-in-regression-and-pca).

Comment: If you use scikit's PCA then it does centering for you.

Answer (score 2):

Per [@amoeba](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28666/amoeba)'s [comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333931/maximum-number-of-principal-components-in-pca-is-sklearn-wrong#comment632330_333931):

> If the number of samples $n$ is less than or equal to the number of
>   features, the $n$-th PC will be constant zero (eigenvalue = 0). This is
>   what sklearn will presumably return. The number of non-trivial PCs is
>   $n−1$ as per the linked answer.

Comment: Could you please explain why this is so?

Comment: Because the rank of PC's matrix should be less than or equal to n. Recall the linear independence.