# Are there special techniques for conducting dimension reduction on nested data?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have 20 items rated on 25 dimensions. Each item was rated on each dimension ~30 times. Each of ~40 participants rated 15 of the 20 items on all of the dimensions.

I had originally thought to do PCA on the item means (i.e. averaging across all ratings for that item), but realized that I will have fewer observations than dimensions, which I understand is not idea for PCA.

My question is, can I do PCA at the *trial level* (i.e. using each individual rating [e.g. participant #1 rating item #1 on dimension #1])? It seems that I should somehow account for the fact that the data are non-independent (i.e. nested within subjects and items). I've seen PCA with random effects mentioned on here, but haven't come across a definitive way to do this.

Is it okay to do PCA at the trial level? Are there additional steps I need to take?

Comment: What is your ultimate analytical goal? There may be other ways to achieve it.

Comment: I am just interested to know if there are underlying factors in the 25 dimensions measured. I had assumed that I needed to account for the fact that ratings came from the same people/items.

Answer (score 1):

> I had originally thought to do PCA on the item means (i.e., averaging across all ratings for that item), but realized that I will have fewer observations than dimensions, which I understand is not idea for PCA.

That's not necessarily the case, for example see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28909/pca-when-the-dimensionality-is-greater-than-the-number-of-samples).

Also you could try models that explicitly handle missing data, like probabilistic matrix factorization. The general term you could google is *low-rank matrix factorization* in the context of recommender systems. For an implementation you can see H2O - see [this example](https://www.slideshare.net/JofaiChow/introduction-to-generalised-lowrank-model-and-missing-values) for slides on application for missing values.

If you're into Python you could also check [this example](https://github.com/lambdaofgod/matrix-factorization) (it uses H2O on Movielens dataset).

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a multilevel factor analysis (Muthén, 1991, 1994; see Reise et al., 2005 for an accessible tutorial, and see Kim et al., 2016, for an updated overview). From  Reise et al., the process sounds pretty straightforward:

1. Conduct a generic EFA, ignoring dependency (gives you a starting, albeit misinformed factor solution).
2. Estimate ICCs for measurements within each item (helps you appraise to what extent the multilevel approach is needed)
3. Conduct factor analysis on within-subject correlation matrix
4. Conduct factor analysis on between-subject correlation matrix

Given Muthén's publishing on this approach, it's a virtual certainty that it can be implemented in Mplus. I don't recall this kind of multilevel functionality for factor analyses in SPSS, and am unsure about what options you might have for R (I know there are packages for specifying multilevel confirmatory models, but unsure about exploratory models).

**References**

Kim, E. S., Dedrick, R. F., Cao, C., & Ferron, J. M. (2016). Multilevel factor analysis: Reporting guidelines and a review of reporting practices. *Multivariate Behavioral Research*, *51*(6), 881-898.

Muthén, B. O. (1991). Multilevel factor analysis of class and student achievement components. *Journal of Educational Measurement*, *28*(4), 338-354.

Muthén, B. O. (1994). Multilevel covariance structure analysis. *Sociological Methods & Research*, *22*(3), 376-398.

Reise, S. P., Ventura, J., Nuechterlein, K. H., & Kim, K. H. (2005). An illustration of multilevel factor analysis. *Journal of Personality Assessment*, *84*(2), 126-136.

Comment: This looks like it might be perfect! It's clear that it can handle multiple nested random factors, but I'm unclear if it can handle multiple crossed random factors?